# How do I detect or watch data changes in APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, api, observers

I will get JSON data from a API, and want to watch for changes in the API. If data changes in the API, I have to fetch the new data and send notifications to my clients.

How do I observe for data changes?
I thought of setting an interval between successive Ajax calls, but it would be an effective way.

Any ideas or libraries available for JavaScript or nodejs that will fire events whenever the data in a API changes?

Answer (score 4):

You have to check data changes in the server side. Like if you update a **blog** and want to send a **notification** to the user about a **blog** is updated then you have to send the **notification (email)** when you updating the **blog** (there will be a **method** or **SQL query** to update the blog data or post).

Please let me know if you addressing different thing.

Comment: I am just consuming an API(can't edit the api) and have built a front-end for displaying the data. The api gives a JSON response. For notification I meant push notifications. So now I think of writing node js for handling push notifications. So how do I observe the api for changes and send push notifications to users?

Comment: After call **API** you are getting a **JSON response**. Based on this **JSON response** you can call another **METHOD** or **API** which will send the push notification.